# Reading 3 Text Files and Finding the Matching Number?

Tags: java, file, text, match

This program needs to read "credit card" numbers from 1 text file, compare them to the 2nd, if there is a match, compare that to the third and then display the number that matches in all 3.

I'm having a lot of trouble and can't figure out whats wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class Search {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { //main method
        boolean match = false;
        String creditNumber = null;
        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("creditCards1.txt"));
        creditNumber = reader1.readLine();
        while(match = false & creditNumber != null){
            System.out.println(creditNumber);
            boolean confirm = false;
            confirm = searchTwo(creditNumber);
            if(confirm == true){
                confirm = searchTwo(creditNumber);      
                System.out.println(confirm);
                break;
            }
        reader1.close();
        }


    }   

    public static boolean searchTwo(String creditNumber) throws IOException { //method for searching the 2nd text file

        boolean match = false;
        String creditNumber2 = null;
        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("creditCards2.txt"));
        creditNumber2 = reader2.readLine();
        while(match = false & creditNumber != null){
            boolean confirm = false;
            confirm = searchThree(creditNumber2);
            if(confirm == true & creditNumber2.equals(creditNumber)){
                match = true;
                System.out.println(creditNumber2);
            }

            creditNumber2 = reader2.readLine();
        }
        reader2.close();
        if(match = true || creditNumber2 == null){
            return match;
        }
        return match;


    }       

public static boolean searchThree(String creditNumber) throws IOException { //method for searching the 3rd text file

        boolean match = false;
        String creditNumber3 = null;
        BufferedReader reader3 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("creditCards3.txt"));
        creditNumber3 = reader3.readLine();

        while(match = false & creditNumber != null){

            if(creditNumber3.equals(creditNumber)){
                match = true;
                break;
            }
            creditNumber3 = reader3.readLine();     

        }
        reader3.close();
        if(match = true || creditNumber3 == null){
            return match;
        }

        return match;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Are you getting any error/exception? You have to give more details

Comment: do you search only for the first creditcard matching in all files, or do you want to search for all creadit cards in all 3 files (more than one)?

Comment: I'm just not getting any output. even the first `System.out.println(creditNumber);` doesn't print when the program runs.

I search every number in every file to see if they have a match. Basically it's 3 text documents with a new cc number on every line.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few things wrong here.

1. you're never setting `match = true` in your `main` and thus it will loop forever.
2. ```
   confirm = searchTwo(creditNumber);
   if(confirm == true){
       confirm = searchTwo(creditNumber);      
       System.out.println(confirm);
       break;
   }
   ```

   this code is redundant.

   `searchTwo()` will return true only if `searchThree()` returns `true`.
3. You are not checking for equality in your `while` loops, you are simply setting the variable.

   ```
   while(match = false & creditNumber != null)
   ```

   should be changed to:

   ```
   while(match == false && creditNumber != null)
   ```
4. You need to be reading a new line inside the while loops, not just once outside it. The way you have this currently, you are only reading the first line of the file.

Answer (score 0):

can you have a look at my solution? it is not perfect, but i think it is scalable...

i created a simple project with the following creditcard files:

**creditCards1.txt:**

```
5416247983974134
5572941594858518
5110952365939493
5154933849210203
5272835420269481
```

**creditCards2.txt:**

```
5562949040660851
5139055358731815
5154933849210203
5152652348339972
5382178174490350
5272835420269481
5564201755352300
5572941594858518
```

**creditCards3a.txt:**

```
5121672532009148
5328229152859756
5272835420269481
5258620703451297
5154933849210203
5411765815619689
```

**creditCards3b.txt:**

```
5121672532009148
5328229152859756
5258620703451297
5411765815619689
```

**creditCards4.txt:**

```
5121672532009148
5328229152859756
5272835420269481
5258620703451297
5411765815619689
```

and then i created the following junit test case:

```
package creditcard.search;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CreditCardSearchTest {

    private CreditCardSearch creditCardSearch;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        creditCardSearch = new CreditCardSearch();
        creditCardSearch.addCreditCardsFile(new File("creditCards1.txt"));
        creditCardSearch.addCreditCardsFile(new File("creditCards2.txt"));
    }

    @Test
    public void assert_creditcards_found_in_2_files() throws IOException {
        final Set<String> creditcards = creditCardSearch.searchForMatchesInAllFiles();

        assertNotNull(creditcards);
        assertEquals(3, creditcards.size());
        assertTrue("5154933849210203", creditcards.contains("5154933849210203"));
        assertTrue("5272835420269481", creditcards.contains("5272835420269481"));
        assertTrue("5572941594858518", creditcards.contains("5572941594858518"));
    }

    @Test
    public void assert_creditcards_found_in_3_files() throws IOException {
        creditCardSearch.addCreditCardsFile(new File("creditCards3a.txt"));

        final Set<String> creditcards = creditCardSearch.searchForMatchesInAllFiles();

        assertNotNull(creditcards);
        assertEquals(2, creditcards.size());
        assertTrue("5154933849210203", creditcards.contains("5154933849210203"));
        assertTrue("5272835420269481", creditcards.contains("5272835420269481"));
    }

    @Test
    public void assert_creditcards_not_found_in_3_files() throws IOException {
        creditCardSearch.addCreditCardsFile(new File("creditCards3b.txt"));

        final Set<String> creditcards = creditCardSearch.searchForMatchesInAllFiles();

        assertNotNull(creditcards);
        assertTrue(creditcards.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void assert_creditcards_found_in_4_files() throws IOException {
        creditCardSearch.addCreditCardsFile(new File("creditCards4.txt"));

        final Set<String> creditcards = creditCardSearch.searchForMatchesInAllFiles();

        assertNotNull(creditcards);
        assertEquals(1, creditcards.size());
        assertTrue("5272835420269481", creditcards.contains("5272835420269481"));
    }
}
```

last but not least the implementation:

```
package creditcard.search;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class CreditCardSearch {

    private final Set<File> files = new HashSet();

    public void addCreditCardsFile(final File file) {
        files.add(file);
    }

    public Set<String> searchForMatchesInAllFiles() throws IOException {
        if(files.size() < 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("a minimum of 2 creditcard files required");
        }

        final Map<Path, List<String>> linesPerPath = new HashMap<>();
        for(final File file : files) {
            final Path path = file.toPath();
            linesPerPath.put(path, Files.readAllLines(path));
        }

        final Set<String> creditcards = new HashSet();

        final Iterator<Path> it = linesPerPath.keySet().iterator();

        List<String> linesA = null;

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (null == linesA) {
                linesA = linesPerPath.get(it.next());
            }
            List<String> linesB = linesPerPath.get(it.next());
            linesA.retainAll(linesB);
        }

        creditcards.addAll(linesA);

        return creditcards;
    }

}
```

junit test results:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: creditcard.search.CreditCardSearchTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.105 sec
```

the code of the project can be found at GitHub: https://github.com/StefanHeimberg/stackoverflow-31952730